# Not able to use Tumblr API v2 to make POST requests

Tags: php, oauth, tumblr

**What I am trying to do:** Connect to the Tumblr API v2 via PHP and be able to create new posts

**The problem:** The API response is always something similar to `Invalid OAuth credentials. Unable to get info`

The strange part is that I am able to connect to the API (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) with no problems when I do a GET request but there must be something I must be doing wrong with my signature when I try to create a POST.

Here is my code:

```
$params = array("type" => "quote", "quote"=>"test" ); 
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, null); 
$token = new OAuthConsumer($access_token['oauth_token'], $consumer_secret); 
$req_req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, 
"POST", 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/MY_URL/post', $params); 
$req_req->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), 
$consumer, $token, null); 
$result = $req_req->to_postdata(); 

$ch = curl_init('http://www.tumblr.com/api/write');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.tumblr.com/api/write'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $result);
```

A `var_dump` of `$result` echoes the following

```
oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxx&oauth_nonce=xxxxxxx&oauth_signature=xxxxxx
&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1325033502&oauth_token=xxxxxx
&oauth_version=1.0"e=test&type=quote
```

I am not sure the `curl_init` must be calling `http://www.tumblr.com/api/write` but I also tried with `api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/post` with no luck

I also checked all the variables to see if the tokens are OK and they seem to be working fine.

Any hint in the right direction will be appreciated as I have went to page 30 of Google and I just see people with the same issue as myself.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having success with [this library](https://github.com/jacobbudin/tumblroauth), which was written around a year ago.

I checked the dump of the result before the curl and it looks more or less the same as yours, so i'm not sure what the difference is.